# How to generate SAS Token and URL for Azure blob in postman?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, postman, salesforce

I want to get SAS URL of a blob through rest api, so that i can use that url to open file in different system(Salesforce).
Can someone help me to get the SAS URL of a blob through postman so that i can implement the same approach in Salesforce.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To generate SAS Token and URL, need to use a few environment variables like account-name, account-key, container name, etc.

- Then, execute the request and use the `SAS` Token QueryString in subsequent requests.
- Before providing the environment variables, copy the azure storage SAS postman.js file to the pre-request script sandbox.
- JSON Payload should be copied into the Postman body.
- The parameters `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers set.

Please refer this [article](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/03/azure-storage-sas-tokens-postman/) for more information.